# Flexslider call back function "after" fire twice

Tags: flexslider

I am loading some data via ajax in flexslider using callback function "after" but I noticed that sometime it fires twice. Anybody having this issue?

example code:

```
$('.flexslider').flexslider({
    animation: "slide",
    after: function(slider){
      console.log('check fire');
    }
  });
```

Comment: Anybody having this issue? #flexslider

Answer (score 0):

At a glance, it sounds like you have more than one `.flexslider` on the page, or being rendered.  2 `.flexslider`'s causes it to fire twice.

Comment: Nope, it's running just once, double checked.